# Find the point on the line $y = 2x + 1$ that is closest to the point $(5, 2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is: Find the point on the line $y = 2x + 1$ that is closest to the point $(5, 2)$.
I know the high (or middle) school method. Create a line that is perpendicular to this line, so the slope will be $-1/2$. Then the intersection is the answer.

But I meet this question from a linear algebra textbook. I want to use projection onto a line method. Projecting vector $b$ onto vector $a$ with the error $e=b-\hat{x}a$.

Thus, $a \cdot (b-\hat{x}a)=0$ or $a\cdot b-\hat{x}a\cdot a=0$.
Thus, $\hat{x}=\frac{a\cdot b}{a\cdot a}$

But the problem is that here $a$ and $b$ are pure vectors. My question is given a specific line. Then I don't know how to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a point on the line, such as $(0,1)$. The vector joining $(0,1)$ to $(5,2)$ is their difference, $(5,1)$. We need to project this in the direction of the line, which is given by $(1,2)$ (to wit, the parametric equation is $L(t)=(0,1)+t(1,2)$). This projection is $$\frac{(5,1)\cdot (1,2)}{(1,2)\cdot (1,2)}(1,2) = \frac{7}{5}(1,2) = \left(\frac{7}{5},\frac{14}{5}\right).$$We obtain the point in the line which is closest to $(5,2)$ by adding this vector to the point $(0,1)$. Thus the point in the line which is closest to $(5,2)$ is $$\left(\frac{7}{5},\frac{19}{5}\right).$$

Comment: 2 follow-up questions. 1. How to get (1,2)? 2. Why do we need to add this vector to the point (0,1)?

Comment: 1. Because, forgetting the $+1$ (which is just a translation), adding $1$ unit to the $x$ variable adds $2$ units to the $y$ variable, i.e., the slope equals $2$; 2. Because we ignored the $+1$ translation in point 1. just explained.

Comment: In other words, it's like we translated everything as to make $(0,1)$ the origin, and solved the problem there. And then unmade the translation to get the correct answer in the original coordinates.

Comment: @IvoTerek, you final answer is not correct. see my answer and also another answer to see why.

Comment: @sirous Thanks for pointing it out. It turned out to be a simple algebra mistake in the first line, which I have already fixed. Now all the answers agree.

Answer (score 1):

Let the point on the line which is closest to (5, 2) be $(x, 2x + 1)$.

Let **a** be a vector from (0,1) to $(x, 2x + 1)$, so **a** $= (x, 2x).$

Let **b** be a vector from (2,5) to $(x, 2x + 1)$, so **b** $= (x-5, 2x-1).$

**a** $\cdot$ **b** = 0$ (since **a** and **b** must be perpendicular to each other)

$x(x-5) + 2x(2x - 1) = 0$

$5x^2 - 7x = 0$

$x = 0$ or $x = \frac{7}{5}$

But $x \neq 0$ so $x = \frac{7}{5}$

Sub $x = \frac{7}{5}$ into $y = 2x + 1$ to get $y = \frac{19}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Calculus solution:

Let d be the distance. the point on line is where it is tangent to a circle with radius d and center (5, 2) and we can write:

$d=\sqrt{(x-5)^2+(y-2)^2}=\sqrt{(x-5)^2+(2x+1-2)^2}=\sqrt{5x^2-14x+26}$

Taking derivative and equating to 0 we get:

$x=\frac 7 5$

$y=\frac {19}5$